# Concatenation+Autofill+Fixed Cell+RCell+Multiple Column Reference Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I believe I'm having an issue with either appropriately identifying a fixed cell or order of operations.  I've spent an hour an a half researching and can't find the answer.  The issue is only with the Concatenation row: I can't get VBA to recognize the insertion of a fixed cell into the text of the formula (I can only get it R the cell).  It's for a daily exported excel report from a database that inserts the date into C2.  I'm concatenating the file names in column B with the folder location they'll be in at the end of the day, the day's date and the unique file group identifier in each matching cell in column C.  I've replaced the text of the folder name with FOLDER for confidentiality purposes.  I can concatenate and autofill it manually, but I'd rather just type the formula in once!  Any assistance would be helpful.

Thanks! - John

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""yyyy mm dd"")"
Range("C2").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
    "=CONCATENATE(""FOLDER,("$C$2"), FOLDER"",RC[1])"
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A5").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5:A" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A5:A" & lastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("A:A").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Rows("1:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B3").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work since the formula is expecting references via the RC notation, but you could try:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
    "=CONCATENATE(""FOLDER,(" & "$C$2" & "), FOLDER"",RC[1])"
```

As an alternative to inserting a fixed cell, an option would be to assign that cell's value to a string variable and than insert that.

```
Dim dateVal as string

dateVal = Range("C2").Value2

Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = 
    "=CONCATENATE(""FOLDER,(" & dateVal & "), FOLDER"",RC[1])"
```

Comment: `$C$2` in R1C1 is `R2C3` without the `[]`. makes it relative to the sheet and absolute reference.